# Selecting multiple items in React-dnd?

Tags: reactjs, react-dnd

[How to drag multiple objects at once in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61469975/how-to-drag-multiple-objects-at-once-in-react)

I've seen it being done with React-draggable, but I am not sure if it's possible to do so with React-DnD. It doesn't seem to be a supported feature from the answers in the past, but since two years has elapsed since then. I am wondering if it's possible now.

[How to Drag & Drop Multiple Elements In React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55750718/how-to-drag-drop-multiple-elements-in-react)

Also, is it possible to swap react-dnd with react-beautiful-dnd, it seems react-beautiful-dnd is only used for lists.